# Howto Get the name of a SWT widget/control at run time

Tags: java, controls, swt

First, I'm new to Java SWT form development, but I have experience with Winforms so I would expect Java/SWT to have so similar functionality.

I'd like to be able to get the name of a SWT widget/control at runtime.

I can see in the designer that each control has a attribute named "Variable", but I don't see a way to access it.

```
// I'd like to be able to do something like this:

Control[] controls = shlMyApplicatioName.getChildren();

for (Control control: controls)
{                    
    System.out.println(control.<some thing here that gets name>);
}
```

Is there some get() method, or some other way to access the control's name?  I saw some examples of setData() and getData(), but it seems silly to have to set something if the information is already available in the control itself.

To clarify, In C# when I'm in a Form object I can do this:

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c.Name);
 }
```

In Java SWT I'd like to do the same sort of looping through the controls and getting the name of each one.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'name', but, no, SWT doesn't have anything like that. Be vary careful looking at internal field names in SWT classes as they can be very different on the various platforms supported by SWT.

Comment: What do you mean by "name of the Control"? `I can see in the designer ...` what designer? What "Variable"? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

SWT does not have anything like the Winforms control name.

You would have to set this using the `setData` and `getData` methods of `Control`.